# Mantras while cooking

Tags: mantras, rituals, food

There are mantras to be recited and practice like Annashuddhi/parishechanam before eating. But are there any mantras to be recited before/while/after cooking to bless the food? Are there some practices to be followed?

Comment: if you are Hari Vayu baktha that is hanuman, than you can chant matharme mathiraswin pithar athula guruho brathar ishttaptha bhandho, 2. swamin sarvantharathman aja jhara rahitha janma mirthuyu mayanam 3. govindha dehi bakthim bavathi cha bhagavan nirjitham nirnimitham 4. nirvayjam nischalam sad guna brahathim sasvathim aasu deva.. solka no. 15 of harivayu stuti by trivikaramapandithacharya on madhva, if you arent hari vayu baktha than hare rama hare krishna rama rama hare hare is enough whatever you cook is another form of god that is anushnadham

Comment: after neivedyam should be performed manasi like bharathi ramana mukhy praanthargatha sri krishnarpnamasthu

Answer (score 1):

You can chant Vishnu Sahasrnama and Lalitha Sahasrnama and excetra.[It says here](https://wisdom.srisriravishankar.org/mantra-to-chant-before-and-after-meals/) . This mantra is Annadata Sukhi Bhava which means the person who is giving me this food let them be happy. This is one mantra that you say when you are cooking.